# Find date diff output as each year

Tags: php

Now I use `date_diff()` to find diff of date

```
public function getDateDiff($date1,$date2){
    $date1 = date_create('2019-12-29');
    $date2 = date_create('2020-01-05');
    $diff = date_diff($date1,$date2); // Diff is 7 days
}
```

I need output as array something like

```
$date1 = date_create('2019-12-29');
$date2 = date_create('2020-01-05');
$diff_array = getDateDiff($date1,$date2);
$diff_array['2019'] = 2; // 29 Dec 2019 - 31 Dec 2019 
$diff_array['2020'] = 5; // 1 Jan 2020 - 5 Jan 2020

$date1 = date_create('2020-10-10');
$date2 = date_create('2020-10-20');  
$diff_array = getDateDiff($date1,$date2);  
$diff_array['2020'] = 10; // 10 Jan 2020 - 20 Jan 2020
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, what if two `$date1` and `$date2`  happens to be on the same year, Then the `$diff_array` will overwrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you can do something like:

1. Get year from each date;
2. If year are equal then `$diff_array[$date1->format("Y")] = $diff_array.format("d");`
3. Else take last day of $date1's year, calculate difference and then `$diff_array[$date1->format("Y")] = $diff_array.format("d");`
4. Take the first day of $date2's year, calculate difference and then `$diff_array[$date2->format("Y")] = $diff_array.format("d");`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

```
   $date='11-12-2010'; 
   Carbon::parse($date)->diffForHumans(); //10 years ago
```

fore compare two date with DateTime ,you can do this for example

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```